# how to get python to add several totals together and print the overall total

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am working on some code for my mock exams and I am stuck on the part where I have to add all the scores together and then print the total. The aim of the code is for 2 players to roll 2 dice, if the numbers are the same, they roll a third die. the code then adds the die together and prints the total depending on if the total can be divided by 2.
after repeating this 5 times, the code should then add all the totals together and display the overall total.
yet it only ever prints the last total, and does not add all 5 totals together. if anyone could help me, that would be appreciated, i am also sorry for the noob question. i am new to this.

```
import random                   
score = 0                      
for i in range(5):
    print ("\n")
    dice1 = random.randint(1,6)
    dice2 = random.randint(1,6)            
    dice3 = random.randint(1,6)
    print ("player 1: roll 1 = ",dice1)
    print ("player 1: roll 2 = ",dice2)         
    if dice1 == dice2:
        print ("player 1: roll 3 = ",dice3)         
    score = dice1+dice2
    if dice1 == dice2:
        score = dice1+dice2+dice3                                 
    if score % 2 == 0:
        score = score+10                   
    if score % 2 == 1:
        score = score-5                    
        print ("player 1: score = ", score)

print ("\n")
overalltotal = score
print ("total for player 1:", overalltotal)
```

i expect the output to be the total of all 5 scores. yet the actual output is only ever the last score

Comment: `score = score + dice1+dice2` and `score = score + dice1 + dice2 + dice3`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You problem is not Python but is program logic. Use a paper and a pencil to first **describe**  what should be done, step by step with tests, loops and blocks. Then follow the process on the paper with different use cases. When you think it should work, translate it it Python code, add trace prints to control what happens  and run. You should be able to fix everything by yourself.

As hints of what should be fixed or improved:

- 2 different `if dice1 == dice2:` tests one after the other. Better to group outside what is common (`score = dice1 + dice2`) and than use one single test for what is specific (`score += dice3`)
- the `print ("player 1: score = ", score)` is inside an if block. Nothing will be printed if `score % 2 != 1`. Is this really desirable?
- initialize `overalltotal` before the main loop, and increment it with `score` inside the loop
- your code always compute `dice3` even when it is not used. Why not only compute it inside the `if dice1 == dice2:` block?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to include overalltotal += score at the end of the for-loop rather than setting overalltotal = score after the for-loop. So your code would be:

```
import random                   
score = 0
overalltotal = 0 # <-- initialize here                      
for i in range(5):
    print ("\n")
    dice1 = random.randint(1,6)
    dice2 = random.randint(1,6)            
    dice3 = random.randint(1,6)
    print ("player 1: roll 1 = ",dice1)
    print ("player 1: roll 2 = ",dice2)         
    if dice1 == dice2:
        print ("player 1: roll 3 = ",dice3)         
    score = dice1+dice2
    if dice1 == dice2:
        score = dice1+dice2+dice3                                 
    if score % 2 == 0:
        score = score+10                   
    if score % 2 == 1:
        score = score-5                    
        print ("player 1: score = ", score)
    overalltotal += score # <-- add value of each round here

print ("\n")
print ("total for player 1:", overalltotal)
```

Comment: Note for beginners: `a += b` is roughly equivalent to `a = a + b`. Same thing for `-=`, `*=`, etc. (Not exactly equivalent, because it is an in-place modification; for details, [follow the links in the doc](https://docs.python.org/3.7/reference/datamodel.html#object.__iadd__))

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change score as you have mentioned then you have to change your statements

```
score = dice1+dice2 --> score += dice1+dice2 (do this for dice things)
score = score+10 --> score += 10 (for score things)
score = score-5 --> score -= 5 (for score things)
```